# Is it possible to write an infinite sentence that is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence, run-on-sentence

I was wondering if this was technically possible in English. I did not know if there are specific grammar rules that would make an infinite sentence impossible.

Comment: What is an “infinite sentence”, what is “grammatically correct”, and why do you care?

Comment: What do you mean by infinite?

Comment: Write a sentence in a circle that ends as it began and you've got it. Otherwise, this is just a novelty, and primarily opinion based.

Comment: By infinite I mean a sentence that can go on forever without stopping, and without breaking any rules of the English language that would make it grammatically impossible. Not to say I plan to write super long sentences in all my papers if someone says that this is acceptable, but I was just curious if it's possible in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is supposedly possible. *Unbounded dependency constructions*, an example of which is relative clause. E.g. *"This is the book, [which [I think you said she recommended]]."* That last set of braces can have more layers of embedded subordinate clauses, and supposedly there is no limit as to the number of layers. 2002 *CGEL* page 1079.

Comment: And of course, there are the trivial examples like *"Kathy invited John, John Jr, John III, . . ., Bob, Bob-Bob, Bob-Bob-Bob, . . ., John-Bob, etc."*

Comment: It's certainly not technically possible for one person to write one.

Comment: No, it's not possible. There can be no infinite-length sentence that is correct because it could never be parsed, hence the grammaticality could not be determined.

Comment: @JohnLawler Smells like you just might be able to reduce that one to the halting problem. :)

Comment: What @medica said. Circular sentences are quit easy to create, and they can be considered infinite, inasmuch as you can simply repeat them over and over without ever creating an ungrammatical sequence—though of course you'll never end up with a complete, finished sentence, either (but that's a side effect of infinity). ***“How I hate what you said about what he thinks about”***, for instance, is recursive and never ends if you start from the top every time you reach the end.

Comment: "There are many such problems, including the *A* problem, the *B* problem, &hellip; &hellip; " <-- it's never ungrammatical. Why the doubt?

Comment: Well, ya can't **finish** writing it :-) .

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet.  If you have that sentence, then just write it on a Mobius strip so that the last word meets the first word and there you have it.

Comment: @JohnLawler you can finish parsing an infinite sequence if you know that it repeats in finite time.

Comment: it's trivial to make a sentence of any given length.  "Very long." is a sentence.  Just repeat the word "very" ("Very very very very long"). There are any number of similar examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no.  A sentence needs punctuation.  After that punctuation it is over.  A sentence fragment can be infinite but not a whole sentence because it has to end.

Comment: This only seems to apply if you compose the sentence from beginning to end.  I could compose "This is a very long sentence." and then add a "very" an infinite number of times.  This sentence would have proper punctuation.

Comment: "A beach can have an infinite [coastline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) but not a whole landmass because it has to be surrounded by water."

Comment: Sentences do not need punctuation. Sentences are spoken, not written. Punctuation is like gasoline; you need it to run the car, but you don't need it to walk.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I agree but he said to write a sentence.

Comment: If it's limited to writing, then grammar and grammatical correctness go out the window (if there's any left to throw by this time). Limiting it to writing reduces it to a rather silly computer game; grammar isn't designed for things like that, any more than humans are designed to fly without machines. This is like asking how far humans could fly if they installed jet engines in their butts.

Comment: @JohnLawler - no more than 500 miles.  I was answering the question making a wide array of assumptions based on common understanding of meanings.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: Not infinitely far, that's for sure.

Comment: @JohnLawler - do those jet engines support light speed? haha

Answer (score 4):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_English_sentence), such a sentence is theoretically possible.

In practice, of course, though the clauses and other structures of even the longest sentence may be notionally separated by such typographical devices as semi-colons, dashes, parentheses and so, in practice that sentence will consist of shorter sentences which might as well be marked off at intervals by full stops/periods as by the various pseudo-periods I've just mentioned.

Comment: How does a sentence have a shorter sentence in it?  Wouldn't that at least be sentences?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd,  What about, "How does a sentence have a shorter sentence in it, wouldn't that at least be sentences?"

Comment: Good start. Got lost along the way. Think again! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason that a computer couldn't be coded to write a recursive sentence along the lines of

> I wrote down a 1, and then I wrote down a 2, and then I wrote down a 3, and then I wrote down a 4, ...

with a simple *k* + 1 increase, indefinitely extended. Of course, a machine wouldn't reach infinity with that operation, any more than computers calculating π or simply counting integers ever would.

But more to the point, it's hard to argue that such a sentence has any theoretical interest, since it amounts to a snippet of language infinitely repeated with one minor and predictable variation in each iteration. Is it grammatically correct? Sure. Is it coherent? Enough so that no one would be tempted to spend more than an extremely finite period of time reading it. But so what?

The problem with the most obvious infinitely long sentences is that their trajectory is too boringly easy to comprehend, not that they are overwhelmingly complicated. And the direction of the simple case is enough to persuade me that the undertaking itself isn't very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

A sentence is only grammatically correct if it can be mentally parsed by speakers/readers of the language in question. Even a sentence with 7+ levels of nested clauses fails to be grammatically correct in this sense, so forget about infinite sentences.

Comment: I agree. I think of the attempts to construct artificially long sentences as akin to trick shots in billiards, especially if they cannot be understood without having to be separately explained.

Answer (score 2):

There is no theoretical limit on the length or depth of a sentence. But

- An *infinite* sentence cannot be uttered, because the utterer will die before it can be completely encoded, and
- An *infinite* sentence cannot be understood, because it cannot definitively decoded until it reaches its end; but a sentence which reaches its end is not infinite.

Comment: What if the person saying the sentence was traveling faster than the speed of light.  Did you even think this thing out properly?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Then we would have a bigger issue on our hands because ordinary matter cannot travel at the speed of light.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... How the hell do you know that?

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Google and current theoretical science, as well as E=MC^2, which states that as your state of energy is greater, it takes exponentially more energy to travel faster.

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... I bet you that given an infinite amount of time, people will travel faster than the speed of light.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I wouldn't know what rules and laws may be broken or better defined in the course of an infinite amount of time, so I won't argue either way on that.  (I think this is getting off-topic though)

Answer (score 2):

There are many constructs to generate infinite sentences:

- I heard that he heard that I heard that he thought that I said that he thought...
- I said "I  said "I said "I said...
- At the casino, I rolled a 1, then a 2, then a 3, then a 1, then a 5, then a 6...

Comment: I love the "I said 'I said "I said 'I said...'"'" one.

Comment: Then just write one of these on a Mobius strip and there you have it. You can read forever and not hit the end, but it has finite size, just like you can walk on a globe infinitely but not be infinitely far from your start.

Comment: @Oldcat: All these constructs can be made so that they never repeat, like pi. Without getting too mathy, for each of these verbs you can assign a number. For example, the first one could assign heard to 1, thought to 2, and said to 3. Then just imagine an irrational number written in base 4. That number has a corresponding infinite sentence that can never be written as a repeating sequence a la a Mobius strip.

Comment: @JoeZ. you might enjoy [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317526/is-is-this-an-example-of-an-example-of-a-bad-question#comment312659_317537) and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317526/is-is-this-an-example-of-an-example-of-a-bad-question#comment312618_317526)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could have a sentence that goes on and on and on and on and .... and on and on and on for an infinitely long time and then stops.

Comment: If it goes "for an infinitely long time," how can it "and then stop?" ;) -- When?